# Python Regex: Split on first occurrence of letter

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to split a string into an initial numeric component and the remaining components, using the first occurrence of a letter as the delimiter, so for example:

```
"123b" -> ["123", "b"]
"12b7.97ap" -> ["12", "b7.97ap"]
```

I'm new to regex and I'm having trouble achieving this... The best I could do is:

```
re.split(r"(\d+)", string)
```

But this returns:

```
["", "123", "b"]
["", "12", "b", "7", ".", "97", "ap"]
```

For the two examples above. I suppose I could then combine all the elements after index 1 into a single string, but I'm sure there's a better way... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So is it "split before the first b" or "split after the initial digits"? Or are both safe?

Comment: I suppose they're both safe? I'm not sure what the difference would be.

Comment: Well for example if the first letter isn't always 'b'.

Comment: Or if there are cases with no leading digits or with nothing after the digits.

Comment: Ah right I see - for my use case it wouldn't always be a "b", and there might not be anything after the digits, but there will always be digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility, first matching digits and then matching the rest:

```
import re

for s in "123b", "12b7.97ap":
    print(re.findall(r'\d+|.+', s))
```

Output:

```
['123', 'b']
['12', 'b7.97ap']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
str = '12b7.97ap'
re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?!\d)', str, 1)
  #=> ["12", "b7.97ap"]
```

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKRIwVZB3dAoyVzP0jyxQJ2Lqyi9AihUpK5hb2Mbk6KpYa8IJIHiBUWZeSUaRal6xQU5mUBGeoWOAlC7joKhpibX//8A)|[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XNYQAO/1)

`split`'s optional third argument (here `1`) is the maximum number of splits to perform.

The regular expression matches the first (zero-width) location (think between successive characters) that follows a digit (`\d`) and does not precede a digit. `(?<=\d)` is a *positive lookbehind*; `(?!\d)` is a *negative lookahead*.

This solution does not require the string to begin with a digit. For example:

```
str = 'Prefix 12b7.97ap'
re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)', str, 1)
  #=> ["Prefix 12", "b7.97ap"]
```

Comment: Slight variation: `(?<=\d)(?!\d)`. In the comments they mentioned that there might not be something after the digits, and then that makes a difference. Not clear which result they'd want then, though.

Comment: @Pychopath, I missed that. Thanks. I've edited.

Comment: Hmm... actually, how about just `r'(?!\d)'`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you read the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for groups in regex. You can form groups in matches by having sup regex you can than reference these matches. A minimal fully working example might look like that:

```
import sys
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line in ['exit', 'q']:
            exit()
        else:
            match = re.search(r'(\d+)(.+)', line)
            print(f"group1: {match.group(1)} | group2: {match.group(2)}")
```

But while considering "good pythonic" solutions or getting a better performance might become handy in the long run your should not worry to much in the beginning.